# Visual Studio 2015, Can not open File error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have converted Visual Studio 2010 project to Visual Studio 2015.
When I build converted project like clean->build or rubuild then I am getting below error

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file '..\..\..\filename.lib
```

I have removed file like .suo, .user, .sdf and restart solution file but still getting same error.

In visual Studio 2010 everything works fine.

Comment: Different compiler versions generally have their projects in separate directory trees. So perhaps `filename` is from another 2010 project that has to be converted first?

Comment: I have converted all the other project which required to compile this project.

Comment: The `..\..\..\ ` indicates three steps up in the directory structure. Apparently the linker cannot find the file there. So it might be somewhere else, or missing.

Comment: I have check at that location and lib file is there. If I only build then I am not getting error, Same project rebuild in VS2010 without any error.